# Cursor movement keys not working properly in jshell on macOS terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, jshell

In the following start to a snippet I had typed some nonsense `asd` that I then hit *backspace* to overwrite:

`jshell> void asd$<3$<3>`

As can be seen instead of backspace I got `$<3` .  Right Arrow similarly does `$<2` . Actually Left Arrow works properly.  I do not have an `~/.inputrc` file.  Also notably `iTerm2` works correctly.

So what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this command because JLine (the library used by jshell to handle command line editing) does not support MacOS:

```
echo "jline.terminal=unix" > $HOME/.jline.rc
```